# javascript passing variables via url

Tags: javascript, html, url, variables

Well, question maybe doesn't correct, but I give a shoot.

My script:

```
<a href="javascript:var%20u=location.href;window.open('http://localhost/url='+u);void(o)" onclick="return false">OMG, testing</a>
```

In real, without javascript url look like:

```
http://localhost/url=google.com
```

In here wanna add this: **&format=txt**

So, the correct url then would be:

```
http://localhost/url=google.com&format=txt
```

- How to add **&format** to the javascript "script" which showed at the
  top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like that :

```
<a href="javascript:var%20u=location.href;window.open('http://localhost/url='+u + '&format=txt');void(o)" onclick="return false">OMG, testing</a>
```

You only have to add the text to the string of your url

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want:

```
<a href="javascript:var%20u=location.href;window.open('http://localhost/url='+u+'&format=txt');void(o)" onclick="return false">OMG, testing</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the link using +, unless I misunderstood the question.

```
<a href="javascript:var%20u=location.href;window.open('http://localhost/url='+u+'&format='+txt);void(o)" onclick="return false">OMG, testing</a>
```

Assumes txt is a variable, otherwise put it all in the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it ,, you have to do same as you did for the localhost

```
<a href="javascript:var%20u=location.href;window.open('http://localhost/url='+u+'&format='+txt);void(o)" onclick="return false">OMG, testing</a>
```